# Fuzzy-search appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event to append a list to html, after that I want to use fuzzy-search to search the content in the list. But as I type in text, the list disappears.

The main idea is like this: 
html:

```
<div class="list">
the appended list goes here
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("selector").on("click",function(){
  $("selector").append("text.....")
});
 // fuzzy-search function
var monkeyList = new List('text-list', { 
 valueNames: ['name']
});
```

my code link: https://codepen.io/BeauBo/pen/gxmpLK?editors=1111